# Can I run Microsoft Office 2010 Home and Student on 64 bit Windows XP?

Tags: ms-office

I have a 64 bit version of Windows XP, and am wondering if I can install Microsoft Office Home and Student 2010 on it. Some of my friends are telling me that I can't install this version of Office on a 64 bit Windows XP machine.

I checked the files on the disc, and it has a 32 bit and 64 bit option.  Can I install the 32 bit version on my 64 bit Windows XP machine?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question is well suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: This does indeed belong on SuperUser. But at the same time, have you considered, y'know, just trying it? Very often doing is much faster and more informative than asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work : http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/12/microsoft-why-office-2010-wont-support-windows-xp-64-bit/

Sorry, Microsoft tought the performance would be too bad on WinXP ! A bit disappointing I know...